# Using AWS Load Balancer shows the IP of EC2 instance in the browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

Being very new to cloud deployment in general I am currently setting up my first load balanced environment with two EC2 instances (web servers) to allow drain stopping back and forth for continuous deployment.

I have the domain name registered and pointing at the load balancer but when I navigate to that domain in my browser the URL bar in the browser shows the end IP address of the EC2 instance as opposed to the domain that points to the load balancer. I realise this is simply a lack of understanding on my part but an explanation of how this should work would be great. I couldn't find anything in the AWS docs (which is strange because they are brilliant).

Comment: how are you pointing your domain at the load balancer? where is the domain registered?

Comment: If you used to have your DNS pointed to one of the instances, and recently changed it, it's possible that the DNS change simply hasn't propagated yet. It usually takes only a few minutes, but sometimes can lag for considerably longer in some regions. This is a great way to check the status of DNS propagation: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.insighttwi.com

Comment: @Mircea The domain is registered with discountdomains.co.nz and iIjust put the AWS name servers in the config there. Then I set up a record set for the domain in Route 53 pointing at the load balancer. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things here:

- the domain itself
- the authority for answering queries related to the domain (who)
- records for the domain (what)

You have to set as you indicated the Amazon DNS servers where your domain is registered, and after that create the proper records. The procedure is described here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html

Depending on the TTLs it may take some time for the changes to propagate (some times it's days).

Now onto the Load Balancer: the load balancer itself has a DNS name. The way you point certain entries in your hosted zone to it, is that you create CNAMES where you indicated that the record is actually an alias for the load balancer.

To completely troubleshoot this I would need the domain and the contents of the hosted zone in Route 53. From what you are describing it sounds like you don't have a load balancer at all and that you've created a CNAME that actually point to and IP address(?).

Comment: The Route 53 record set points to the load balancers DNS Name as an alias but as an A not a CNAME. when I choose CNAME the load balancer doesn't pop up in the options. Can you explain to me why it should be a CNAME and not an A?

Comment: https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/ an A record maps a name to an IP. Is the load balancer or the EC2 instance poping up in the options? In the browser do you get something that looks like and IP or it's simply an ip? What's the domain name?

Comment: It actually worked for brief period this afternoon. It forwarded me to the instance and didn't show the instances IP in the browser. I assume that it was a matter of waiting for full propagation of the record. I then twiddled a few things and now its not working at all... It seems that Sydney and China are still stuck on the old dns record... :(

Comment: I needed to flush my local DNS cache. Thanks for your help.